# Math not returning the proper values

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I have i3 in a sqlite base, along with i5, i7, and i9. I want for every one that there is it multiplies and returns an integer

```
const xmrhashrate = score.i3*1500+score.i5*2500+score.i7*4000+score.i9+5000
```

In the score there is only 1 for i3 and when i log it to console it prints out 6500 when its supposed to print out 1500

Comment: please provide all of the values... also maybe order of operations?

Comment: log also score.i3, score.i5, etc. and let us see please

Comment: Without knowing more of the problem, we can't say for sure. But this looks suspicious: `score.i9+5000`. Is that supposed to be multiplied instead of added?

Comment: oups my bad I didnt notice that

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you're exactly 5000 off of the expected value. The reason is you're adding 5000 at the end instead of multiplying.

```
const xmrhashrate = score.i3*1500+score.i5*2500+score.i7*4000+score.i9*5000
```